# PhpStorm can´t connect to Vagrant to add a remote PHP interpreter (private key not found)

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to connect to my Vagrant VM to add a remote PHP interpreter. I use the Vagrant option, but when I try to connect I get this error:
[image]

[image]

I checked if the `private_key` file exists and it does and it contains a valid private key, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to connect with a simple SSH connection with PHPStorm into your vagrant ? The question for more understand if is PHP remote interpreter or SSH connection.

Comment: yes, if i try that I get a Algorithm negotiation fail error. I tried using 127.0.0.1 and por 2222 and also 192.168.56.150 and port 22, user vagrant with no password. Both cases same error

Comment: what is the ip notice on your vagrantFile ?

Comment: config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8088
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 33060
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.150"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Enter into your vagrant and fix password for user vagrant (example vagrant/vagrant)
2. create deployement PHPStorm with SFTP type connection
3. SFTP host = your vagrantFile private network ip
4. port = 22
5. Root path = /var/wwww
6. username = vagrant
7. auth type = password
8. password = vagrant

After you can try this connection with click on 'Test SFTP connection'.
If this test run correctly You are sure that your connection SSH into your vagrant is good.

Try the same with Remote PHP interpreter

Comment: Hi, thanks! this helped debugging this and find a workaround: https://blog.lysender.com/2015/06/phpstorm-sftp-to-a-linux-machine/

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Vagrant 1.7.4 resolve this problem